# If condition to return different data by clicking on different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a function which can return different data when different buttons are clicked. Please take a look at my code and suggest me the desired changes, your valuable time is highly appreciated.

```js
function getData() {
   if($('data1 option:checked')){
      const data1 = mainData().map(d => ({...d, x:d.x*10}));
      return data1;
   }
   else if($('data2 option:checked')){
      const data2 = mainData().map(d => ({...d, x:d.x*25}));
      return data2;
   }
   else if($('data3 option:checked')){
      const data3 = mainData().map(d => ({...d, x:d.x*13}));
      return data3;
   }
   else if($('data4 option:checked')){
      const data4 = mainData().map(d => ({...d, x:d.x*17}));
      return data4;
   }
};
```

```html
<select id = "dropdown">
<option class='data1'>data1</option>
<option class='data2'>data2</option>
<option class='data3'>data3</option>
<option class='data4'>data4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues, such as invalid selectors (ie. `data1` is the class and it's on the `option` itself so it would be `option.data1`), using `:checked` on an `option` element instead of `:selected` and using jQuery objects directly in `if` conditions (which won't work as an object always coerces to `true` value, use the `length` property instead).

That being the said, you can make fix the logic and make it work more efficiently by putting a `value` attribute in your `option` elements which is the figure used in their relative conditions of the `if` statement. Then you can hook your event handler to the `change` of the `select` and perform your logic without the need for the `if` statement at all. Try this:

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="10">data1</option>
  <option value="25">data2</option>
  <option value="13">data3</option>
  <option value="17">data4</option>
</select>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    let optionValue = this.value;
    let data = mainData().map(d => ({ 
      ...d,
      x: d.x * optionValue
    }));

    // use data here...
  }); 
});
```